# Change color of the legend and the lines in chartJSRadar

Tags: r, jscharts

I'm trying to build a radar chart with the `chartJSRadar` function.

Here is the result :
[image]

And I would like to change the colors but I did'nt find how.. If someone knows it will be so helpfull for me

Thank you,

Elise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

> colMatrix:
> Numeric matrix of rgb colour values. If NULL defaults are used

So try adding a matrix with the desired colors in rgb format to your plotting command. For example the following matrix would produce red, green and blue:

```
matrix(c(255,0,0,0,255,0,0,0,255), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  255    0    0
[2,]    0  255    0
[3,]    0    0  255
```

Here an example using the generated matrix. You would need 4 vecors in your column. So e.g.

```
chartJSRadar(..., colMatrix=matrix(c(255,0,0,0,255,0,0,0,255,111,111,111), nrow = 3, ncol = 4))
```